# Interpretation of GAM

Tags: generalized-additive-model

I have used a training dataset to fit parameters via a GAM. I used a gam plot to visualize the fit. When modelling the dependent variable as a smooth function of the independent variable, what is the scale of the y-axis that I should use, and how is this plot best interpreted? For example, what does the zero in the y-axis mean? Is it possible that I could find an optimized value for the independent variable using this plot?

**Here is the explanation of what I am trying to find**.
I am using single predictor to model my response variable.Let us consider my predictor variable is B.I am varying B from 21 to 51. A is the response variable.I got the values for my response variable from running my script for a particular project.
 [image]
The above dataset (Let's say it as A_B) represents, the variation in A as I vary B.My objective is to fit this data using GAM.The function which I am using is
**model_1 = gam(A~s(B,df=3),data=A_B)**. I used "gam" plot for visualizing my fitted model. [image]

In the above figure, what is the scale of the y-axis.My response variable can't have negative numbers and the numbers along y-axis are both positive and negative.How do I interpret this graph?

Comment: Does the term "gam plot" have a standard meaning? Even if it does, you will get more answers, and benefit more readers, by explaining what it is.

Comment: Thanks @NickCox. gam plot is used to plot the smoothed function fitted by generalized additive model (GAM). Please follow the [link](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/mgcv/plot.gam)

Comment: No thanks; questions here really should be self-contained. Links are fine in support, but not as prerequisites. We should **not** need to go off and read some document before we can understand your question. Note that the absence of any reply is a collective signal that people do not understand well enough what you are seeking.

Comment: From your link: "...and plots the component smooth functions that make it up, **on the scale of the linear predictor**."

Comment: So, does it mean that, the values in y-axis are the coefficients of various values of the predictor variable?

Comment: @AshwaniKumar How much do you understand about GAMs?  Coefficients are not a concept that makes sense in this context.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Not so much. I applied the GAM model in R to my dataset and then, trying to analyse the gam plot. The problem which I am facing is with the interpretation of positive and negative numbers along y-axis because the predictor variable which I am using cannot have negative values. Please help.

Comment: Sure.  But first, could you edit your question to give some detailed description of your response variable A?

Comment: you have a tiny dataset with only two variables.  A GAM makes no sense.  Just plot the data -- you'll get everything you need just doing so.  If you had a larger bivariate dataset and were hell-bent on nonparametrics, I'd tell you to use loess, with bootstrapping for the confidence intervals.

Comment: @ACD I have shown here a tiny dataset with just one variable. My original dataset is big and has 3 predictor variable. I also tried to apply linear, polynomial and loess, but GAM outweighed all of them. My problem now is the interpretation part. I have been researching about this and so far I could conclude that the values in y-axis are the numbers which should be multiplied by the smooth functions. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: How many observations?  Also, the "G" in "GAM" is for handling non-gaussian data.  If you haven't already, read up on GLMs before trying to use GAMs, which are harder.  Interpretation of GAM output follows easily if you understand GLMs.

Comment: Another thing that might not be obvious:  read up on splines.  GAMs use splines.  The internet has many good resources that explain them.

Comment: Finally, your example appears to be an unpenalized linear spline, with the knot chosen agnostically.  If you agnostically choose your knots, you should specify more of them, and apply penalization.  If you don't understand what I am talking about, you should probably just use a GLM.  Simon Wood's book on GAMs is a good intro both to GLMs and GAMs.